# Azure Role Service can`t deploy - WaHostBootstrapper.exe.config missing

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles

I`m trying to deploy New Azure Service (using SDK 2.9) and encounter the following error:

- The file provided is not a valid service package.
  Invalid application runtime - a runtime component is missing:/base/x64/WaHostBootstrapper.exe.config.
  [Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdCCO.png)

What did I try:

1. Tried to package the service and saw "base/x64/WaHostBootstrapper.exe.config" exists and not missing. [Screenshot of the Package Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUMAR.png)
2. Tried to deploy other service from different workload (also SDK 2.9) it works.
3. Tried to compare the content of WaHostBootstrapper.exe.config between the to mentioned sevices and it was identical

Attaching the contents of the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
 <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" />
  <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727" />
 </startup>
 <runtime>
  <NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="false" />
 </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Any ideas what else can I check or try to do?
Thanks a lot for you help

Comment: According to your description, I couldn't repro your issue. I also created a test worker role on my side and publish to the azure. It works well. I guess maybe something wrong with the work application. I suggest you could create a new application with the same work role application and test again.

Comment: I have different application with the same worker role running already. We are trying to make our workload smaller so I am extracting the role to different workload. Anything noticeable seems exact the same between the 2, but obviously there is a difference, I am just clueless where to look for it.